# Use Memory Effectively And Less Volume

Tags: java, android

How we can compress the amount of memory used in the application
I checked the application memory consumption on the profile 'App' and found that the application consumes about 35 megabytes of phone memory and this is considered inefficient

Comment: This is considered inefficient as compared to _what_?  If you have a large app, but it does many things, then 35MB doesn't strike me as unreasonable.

Comment: The application contains many activities so I do not know if this causes this size
It also has pictures, but the activities do not contain many comendats. Each activity contains simple instructions to execute only one thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use java memory heap analyzer to identify the parts of your application that use up most of the memory. You can then either optimize your data structures, or decide release parts of the data by setting all references to it to null.

Unintended references to data that is not needed anymore are also refered as "memory leaks". Settings those references to null will cause the garbage collector to remove it from java memory heap.

Use WeakReferences this will help you

A weak reference, simply put, is a reference that isn't strong enough to force an object to remain in memory. Weak references allow you to leverage the garbage collector's ability to determine reachability for you, so you don't have to do it yourself.